# Is there a way to use a wifi adapter to provide internet instead of receive it?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, internet, wireless-access-point

Today i spill coke over my modem and router, and only the modem survived.

I have one of these [wifi adapters (alfa awus036h)](http://www.alfa.com.tw/products_show.php?pc=34&ps=92), I was wondering if I could setup something temporarily to provide wifi internet to my laptop and other devices until I get a new router.

i was thinking maybe I could setup an ad-hoc network with the adapter and then share the internet connection which btw, the modem is connected directly to my main PC ethernet card.

Does someone has any idea how to do this? I am using Linux (Ubuntu 12.04.2)

Comment: Your router survived so you want to replace it with your PC???

Comment: Sorry only the modem survived not the router, the router died, it just keep all the lights on and doesn't respond to resets or anything. So I want to know if I could setup some sort of wireless network with that wifi adapter and then share the internet connection that I use on my main pc that comes from the modem connected to the ethernet card.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but I would only do it short term, your performance through a PC, especially through USB will not be very good for throughput (The max data of USB 2 is no where near most modern broadband connections).

[this is for Ubuntu 10.4 I believe...](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1488953)

Answer (score 0):

Take the router apart. Wash the circuit board to remove the dried corn syrup from it; the sugars in the High Fructose Corn Syrup in Coke are electrical conductors, and are probably shorting out the circuit board so current is not flowing where it should, and the router won't work.

Any obvious scorch marks or otherwise damaged components?  Do you smell burnt rosin?

> If not, put it in a paper bag and point a hair dryer into the bag and
>   let that run for 15 minutes.
>
> If you have no hair dryer, put your oven on WARM (lowest setting,
>   about 160 degrees Fahrenheit/70 Centigrade for 30 minutes, turn the
>   oven off, and put the circuit board on a plate and in the oven, again,
>   for about 15 minutes.

Then, remove it, and put the plate on a table to cool.

The next morning, put the modem back together.  Does it light up when you plug it in?